# Global style - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to apply styles and I have a problem. I have this global style (note that I use MahApps)

```
<Style TargetType = "{x: Type DataGridCell}"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property = "Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType = "{x: Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment = "Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment = "Center" />
                    </ Grid>
                </ ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </ Setter>
</ Style>
```

What it does is to center the contents of a cell in a DataGrid. That works perfectly. The problem is when I want to nest another style in the .xaml of my window.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DefaultDateTimeToHyphenStyle}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource CellForegroundColorDateConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

If I apply that style, the global style (in that cell) stops working. Align the text to the left. What is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try this BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}". Since you derived the style from MetroDataGridCell, the global style will get ignored.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian thx for reply, but not work :(

Comment: Give a key to global style and do based on that.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian Wait! :) If it works, I was looking at another screen O.o. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you inherit your style from {StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}
Change it to {StaticResource {x: Type DataGridCell}} and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in WPF for any particular element only one Style can be applied.